# Why does BitBucket OAuth request_token API always return 400 "Could not verify OAuth request."?

Tags: c#, api, oauth, bitbucket-api

I've been banging my head against the desk for about a whole week trying to make the BitBucket OAuth API work and I can't even get a single request token for saving my own life. The code I made here works with LinkedIn, but BitBucket always returns HTTP status code 400 with a very verbose and helpful message: "Could not verify OAuth request".

It's a simple code (50 lines, couldn't make it shorter) and it is that way because I need to implement OAuth manually, else I wouldn't be asking here and using other external libraries but due to company's requirement I'm not allowed to use external libs in this project. I don't see what's wrong though, 1.0a isn't that hard and getting a request token shouldn't take this long. What could be wrong?

I've also checked my timestamp and it's good, w32tm.exe against pool.ntp.org returns the time with a +30 or something. I've also tried adding and removing 30 minutes to the UtcNow timestamp without success, but my clock is correctly synced (with local time and correct GMT values (GMT -4:30)) so it makes no sense at all.

Could it be because I'm behind a company firewall (Forefront)? but then, why does LinkedIn's API calls work and BitBucket don't? I've also read a **lot** of documents such as the OAuth Bible, the RFCs, official documents, etc. And of course made an extensive search on SO before asking and looked at **all** the links shown in the "Similar Questions" panel before hitting the "Post your question" button.

Here's the simple code (C#):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace OAuthTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String key = "KEY";
            String secret = "SECRET";
            String requestUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token";

            string sigBaseStringParams = "oauth_consumer_key=" + key;
            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + GetNonce();
            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=" + "HMAC-SHA1";
            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + GetTimeStamp();
            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3Fdump";
            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
            string sigBaseString = "POST&";
            sigBaseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(requestUrl) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sigBaseStringParams);

            string signature = GetSignature(sigBaseString, secret);

            Console.WriteLine(PostData(requestUrl, sigBaseStringParams + "&oauth_signature=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(signature)));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static string GetNonce()
        {
            return new Random().Next(1000000000).ToString();
        }

        public static string GetTimeStamp()
        {
            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
            return Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
        }

        public static String PostData(string url, string postData)
        {
            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            return w.UploadString(url, postData);
        }

        public static string GetSignature(string sigBaseString, string consumerSecretKey, string requestTokenSecretKey = null)
        {
            HMACSHA1 hmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1();
            String signingKey = string.Format("{0}&{1}", consumerSecretKey, !string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTokenSecretKey) ? requestTokenSecretKey : "");
            hmacsha1.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signingKey);            
            return Convert.ToBase64String(hmacsha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sigBaseString)));
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit:** Here's a fiddler and browser capture by request:

[image: FiddlerAndBrowser]

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 2:** I made a new test, using the [OAuthBase.cs](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs) class provided by n0741337's suggestion, however, that class does not comply with the 1.0A spec where it asks for a callback method (which at least Bitbucket is kind enough to say that such parameter is required) so I had to modify it so it included the callback parameter in the base signature string (in raw format without encoding). Same results though (I figured it doesn't matter if I show my key since you won't be seeing my secret key anyways), here's a capture:

[image: Fiddler2]

And here's the signature base string:

```
GET&https%3A%2F%2Fbitbucket.org%2Fapi%2F1.0%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2F%26oauth_consumer_key%3Dkey%26oauth_nonce%3D8231861%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1423671576%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Also, to put my code in doubt, one can also use [this class](http://www.timpinkawa.net/misc/oauthbasetwitter.html) I found which someone already adapted for Twitter (though Twitter is blocked in my workplace so I can't test against it), but the results are the same.

Here's the new code I made which uses such classes:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using OAuth;

namespace OAuthTest1
{
    public class oauth2
    {

        public static void Run()
        {
            OAuthBase a = new OAuthBase();
            String nonce = a.GenerateNonce();
            String ts = a.GenerateTimeStamp();
            String key = "key";
            String secret = "secret";
            String requestUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token";

            String normalizedUrl, normalizedArgs;
            String sigBase = a.GenerateSignatureBase(
                new Uri(requestUrl),
                key,
                null,
                secret,
                "http://localhost:4000/",
                "GET",
                ts,
                nonce,
                "HMAC-SHA1",
                out normalizedUrl,
                out normalizedArgs
            );
            String sig = a.GenerateSignatureUsingHash(sigBase, new HMACSHA1());

            String GETArgs = String.Empty;
            GETArgs += "oauth_consumer_key=" + key;
            GETArgs += "&oauth_nonce=" + nonce;
            GETArgs += "&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1";
            GETArgs += "&oauth_timestamp=" + ts;
            GETArgs += "&oauth_version=1.0";
            GETArgs += "&oauth_callback=" + a.UrlEncode("http://localhost:4000/");
            GETArgs += "&oauth_signature=" + sig;

            WebClient w = new WebClient();
            Console.WriteLine(w.DownloadString(requestUrl + "?" + GETArgs));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

**Question for Edit 2:** Does anyone know of an app which connects to Bitbucket's service through this method so I can run Fiddler and see what it is sending? If I could see some output I could at least replicate the flow :/ I've tried against SourceTree but it doesn't work very well.

**Edit 3:** By AZ.'s suggestion I changed the timestamp generation code with this, but it doesn't work anyways :(. Timestamp values look okay though, there's only a slight difference of 5 seconds between my timestamp and the server's:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
String timeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
```

Also, I notice the signature contains a "+" which should've been encoded to %20, which I did when I noticed this after editing the question and it doesn't work either, just FYI.

[image: Fiddler3]

Comment: Is that really a 'failed to obtain request token (status: 400 data: Could not verify OAuth request.) error? run fiddler, try it again in your browser and you should hopefully get a more verbose message.

Comment: Yup! I've added a screenshot so you can see the exact issue :)

Comment: 1. Is the callback accepted by bitbucket... 2. Does the callback require a REST endpoint? I believe it will most likely require a valid public url... not google :D

Comment: btw I've seen some saying bitbucket must be within 5 mins of system clock... where you get 30 mins from?

Comment: About the questions, I don't know the answers for 1 or 2, and there are no documents that can clarify that :/ ... I've tried other URLs, even from other known online services and it doesn't work either. The 30 mins difference I get it from the w32tm.exe output. I don't have the ports open today to test, but I get it in this similar output: "08:38:57 d:+00.0417301s o:+30.1024506s [ * ]"

Comment: I'm off home now but... according to https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/OAuth+on+Bitbucket it must be within a few minutes "The number of seconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT. The timestamp value MUST be a positive integer and MUST be equal or greater than the timestamp used in previous requests. If the timestamp is not within a few minutes either side of the actual current time, the request may be rejected."

Comment: Yes, but there are no references on what date and time does the Bitbucket server has. How do I get its local time? In the code I'm relying in UTC and other codes on the web do so, too, Also, though you're right, I am passing the signature! take a look at the screenshot and the code, it's on the last parameter. I can't add the signature in-between because it must be calculated with the rest of the arguments, so that's why it's in the end. The method is okay too, HMAC-SHA1 as you can see in the screenshot :(

Comment: Can you post what `sigBaseString` looks like after its construction?  Also - does recommended code like [this http://oauth.net/code/ recommended C# class](http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs) work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @n0741337, I've updated the OP with your suggestion's results and the sigBaseString output (in the second sample though, which, according to the class you suggested *should* generate it correctly, but it seems Bitbucket still doesn't like it :( ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your program:

- You're not sending the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header, which makes the POST body unintelligible (it's generally recommended to use the Authorization request header).
- You are not creating the signature base string correctly. The signature base string is the most delicate part of OAuth 1.0, as both client and server MUST independently produce exactly the same byte sequence. With the `oauth_callback` you got the ordering of the parameters wrong (http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#anchor14)

Here's the patch to make the program work:

```
--- Program.cs  2015-02-23 23:13:03.000000000 -0800
+++ Program3.cs 2015-02-23 23:20:37.000000000 -0800
@@ -15,11 +15,12 @@
             String secret = "SECRET";
             String requestUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/api/1.0/oauth/request_token";

-            string sigBaseStringParams = "oauth_consumer_key=" + key;
+            string sigBaseStringParams = "";
+            sigBaseStringParams += "oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3Fdump";
+            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_consumer_key=" + key;
             sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_nonce=" + GetNonce();
             sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_signature_method=" + "HMAC-SHA1";
             sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_timestamp=" + GetTimeStamp();
-            sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Flocal%3Fdump";
             sigBaseStringParams += "&" + "oauth_version=1.0";
             string sigBaseString = "POST&";
             sigBaseString += Uri.EscapeDataString(requestUrl) + "&" + Uri.EscapeDataString(sigBaseStringParams);
@@ -44,6 +45,7 @@
         public static String PostData(string url, string postData)
         {
             WebClient w = new WebClient();
+            w.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
             return w.UploadString(url, postData);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the cause but this line is smelly:

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

You are subtracting a DateTimeKind.Unspecified date from an UTC one. I don't have an environment available to test this but constructing the 1970 date as UTC might help

Comment: Well, while your suggestion is actually very true because the original code (both mine and the one provided by oauth) don't use full UTC dates, I changed the timestamp generation code to this: `TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc); String timeStamp = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();` but the result is still the same. I've updated the OP with a new screenshot of the data I'm generating and comparing it to Bitbucket's server.

Comment: the the issue is somewhere else :(.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is that you are debugging this on your local dev server, and this URL you are sending as a callback URL is useless to a client that is on the Internet:

```
GETArgs += "&oauth_callback=" + a.UrlEncode("http://localhost:4000/");
```

I haven't read the docs for BitBucket, but the way the Google OAuth is implemented is that you need to have a publicly accessible URL for the callback message to be sent to in order for the handshake to work.

This URL isn't called back by your browser, it is called from *their server*, so it must be Internet accessible.